# Jordan form and determinant divisor or elementary divisor

Tags: matrix-decomposition, jordan-normal-form

Say let there be three matrices $X_1,\,X_2,\,X_3$ whose Jordan form are
\begin{equation}
P_1^{-1}X_1P_1=
\begin{pmatrix}
 \lambda & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & \lambda & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & \lambda  
\end{pmatrix}
,\quad P_2^{-1}X_2P_2= 
\begin{pmatrix}
 \lambda &1 & 0 \\
 0 & \lambda & 1 \\
 0 & 0 & \lambda  
\end{pmatrix}
,\quad P_3^{-1}X_3P_3= 
\begin{pmatrix}
 \lambda &1 & 0 \\
 0 & \lambda & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & \lambda  
\end{pmatrix}
.
\end{equation}
I understand that for each matrix there are 3,1,2 linearly independent eigenvectors.
Is there any difference between these in terms of determinant divisors or elementary divisor?
I ask this question from curiosity.
Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by "determinant divisor"?

Comment: @Ken: $d_i(A)$( i-th determinant divisor) at this page.